# Unavailable resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

it have been one day my group and I are not able to connect to our vm, neither to move clone it in other geographic regions (copied machine image and instanciate in region always fail due to lack of resources).

We need it for a tight deadline we have for tomorrow night and we still need to debug some code and the model would not run on our local machines.

What can we try?

The machine is an 8cpu with tesla p100 gpu.

Here's some error messages... do we get a prize if we get one from every part of the world?

```
The zone 'projects/dlfav-275012/zones/us-west1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later. 

The zone 'projects/dlfav-275012/zones/asia-east1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later. 

The zone 'projects/dlfav-275012/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later. 

The zone 'projects/dlfav-275012/zones/europe-west1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

Thank you for your suggestions/solutions :)

Comment: Try selecting a different instance size. The smaller the instance size (cheaper) the more in demand they are (usually). Capacity might be available with a larger instance. Another option is to create an image of the instance and then deploy the image in another region.

Comment: We were able to start the machine without GPU. What do you mean by bigger instance size? Bigger processor and more GPUs?

Comment: A bigger instance has more cpus and more memory. The point is to try selecting a "different" instance size to see if that is available. Based upon your comment, you now know that it is GPU availability that is your problem.

Comment: Though it won't help in the immediate situation, you may consider [purchasing a reservation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for the resources you want to be available in the future.  That way Google will guarantee they will be available (but you will pay for them continuously).